# Taylor theorem for certain functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am working on a PDE, which requires solutions to be both in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^1_b(\mathbb{R}^+)$, the Banach space on continuously differentiable bounded fcts with bounded derivatives. I would like to be able to take such a function and expand it, i.e. use Taylor's Theorem, close to $x=0$ for $x>0$, that is
$$
f(x)=f_0+f_1 x + R(x),\text{ where }f_0, f_1\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{R(x)}{x}=0.
$$
I can think of a function that behaves close to $x=0$ as
$$
f=1+x\cos(\ln(x))+...
$$
in $C^1_b(\mathbb{R}^+)$ but that cannot be expanded as I want. And both $f$ and $f'$ are integrable through $x=0$. Is that right or am saying something wrong? For example, it seems like the function
$$
f=(1+x\cos(\ln(x)))e^{-|x|}
$$
is both in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^1_b(\mathbb{R}^+)$ but it cannot be expanded like I want. Is that a good counter-example?

I just want someone to tell me which is true: can I expand such functions or is my example showing that I cannot in general.

If my counter-example is right, can I at least say that $f-f_0$ is $\mathcal{O}(x)$ in the sense that
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|f-f_0|}{x}<\infty ?
$$

Answer (score 1):

You cant really use Taylor's theorem directly since your function is not $C^\infty$. Moreover, if your function is just $C^\infty$ and not analytic, it can happen that (allthough you can formally write it down) its taylor series does not converge in a neighbourhood of $0$ but just at $x = 0$ itself:

For a standard example consider the function $$f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, \quad &\text{if } x \leq 0, \\
\mathrm e^{-1/x^2} &\text{if } x > 0.
\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is in $C^\infty$ but one has $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Thus the Taylor series of $f$ around converges to $f$ only at $x = 0$. So one cannot represent $f$ as a Taylor series in any neighbourhood of $0$.

However, in your case one can still use the basic idea that underlies Taylor's theorem and this works as follows: Let $f \in C_b^1(\mathbb R^+) \cap H^1(\mathbb R)$ and let $$R \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb C, \quad R(x) := f(x) - (f(0) - f'(0) x).$$ Note that the term in the parenthesis is just the Taylor polynom of $f$ in $x = 0$ of degree $1$. And by the given regularity of $f$ the function is well-defined. Also on clearly has $R \in C^1(\mathbb R^+)$.

To see that $R \in H^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ fix $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Then one has
\begin{align*}
\langle R', \varphi \rangle &= - \langle R, \varphi' \rangle = -\int_{\mathbb R} (f(x) - (f(0) - f'(0) x)) \varphi'(x) \, \mathrm d x \\
&= \langle f' + f'(0) \mathbb 1, \varphi \rangle.
\end{align*}
Since $f' + f'(0) \mathbb 1 \in L^2_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ and $\varphi$ was arbitrarily chosen, one has $R \in H^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R)$. So all in all we have $R \in C^1(\mathbb R^+) \cap H^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R)$. Note that $R$ is generally not bounded on $\mathbb R$ but bounded on every compact set. Analogously, generally $R' \not \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ but you still have $R \in L^2(K)$ for each compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb R$. That should be enough for your application I guess. However, in the special case where $f'(0) = 0$ one has actually $R \in C_b^1(\mathbb R^+) \cap H^1(\mathbb R)$.

Now we finally come to the approximation in a neighbourhood of $0$. We have
$$ \left\lvert \frac{g(x)}{x} \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{f(x) - (f(0) - f'(0) x)}{x} \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} - f'(0)\right\rvert \longrightarrow 0$$
as $x \searrow 0$ since $f \in C_b^1(\mathbb R^+)$. Hence, using your notation set $f_1 := f(0)$ and $f_1 := f'(0)$. Then you get your desired approximation. I didn't thought about your example since it is clear that $f \in C_b^1(\mathbb R^+) \cap H^1(\mathbb R)$ is sufficient to obtain your approximation. Maybe you had additional properties in mind? I don't know that really. So probably it is best to leave it up to you to figure out how your example relates to my ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much. My issue is this: $f$ is in $C^1_b(\mathbb{R}^+)$, so how can you write $f'(0)$? The set $\mathbb{R}^+$ consists of the positive real numbers (not including zero). So $f'(x)$ is continuous and bounded for $x>0$.